# Loading in environment variables to Google Cloud Build using a file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm looking to setup a environment variables (they don't have to be encrypted) for Cloud Build.

`env.sh`

```
export GCP_PROJECT_ID=example
export GCP_KMS_KEYRING=example-secrets
export GCP_KMS_KEYNAME=example-identity
export GCP_KMS_ROLE=roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyDecrypter
export GCP_KMS_KEY_ID=projects/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/locations/global/keyRings/$GCP_KMS_KEYRING/cryptoKeys/$GCP_KMS_KEYNAME
```

`cloudbuild.yaml`

```
steps:
# 1 Install Dependencies
- name: 'python'
  id: Pip install
  args: ['pip3', 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt', '--user']
# 2 Set env variables for its execution
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash', 'scripts/env.sh']
# 3 Run Tests
- name: 'python'
  args: ['python3', '-m', 'pytest', 'functions/test/']
```

Running step 2 does not set these properly. I get no errors when running the script, but later in my tests when I attempt to grab `GCP_KMS_KEY_ID` from `os.env`, I get an error. I understand I can set `env:` under the run tests step, but my project requires loading an env from a file.

What is the best practice to setting up environment variables?

Comment: The problem is you are launching a new bash shell. You want to have the current shell run env.sh. I have not tried this with Cloud Build but in normal Linux you would replace `bash` with `source` as in `source ./scripts/env.sh`

Comment: @JohnHanley That also didn't work but good suggestion. For `gcloud functions deploy` there is a flag `--env-vars-file` that takes a `.yaml` file. Do you know if there is an equivalent for pytest?

Answer (score 2):

You can set env variables and substitutions for the entire build as well instead of just build step.  For your variables, I would suggest having a combo of substitutions and  env variables.

```
steps:
- name: 'python'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    # subs must being with _
    echo $_NAME
    echo $_GREETING
    # env vars called with double $
    echo $$MESSAGE
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash', '-c', 'echo $$MESSAGE']

substitutions:
    _NAME: sam
    _GREETING: hello
options:
    env:
    - MESSAGE=$_GREETING, $_NAME!
```

From your example, it could work to have

```
substitutions:
    _GCP_PROJECT_ID: example
    _GCP_KMS_KEYRING: example-secrets
    _GCP_KMS_KEYNAME: example-identity
    _GCP_KMS_ROLE: roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyDecrypter
options:
    env:
    - GCP_KMS_KEY_ID=projects/$_GCP_PROJECT_ID/locations/global/keyRings/$_GCP_KMS_KEYRING/cryptoKeys/$_GCP_KMS_KEYNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

How about combine step 2 into step 3?

```
args: ['bash', 'scripts/envs.h', '&&', 'python3', '-m', 'pytest', 'functions/test/']
```